# we did not send a packet, disable method

Tags: ssh-keys, ibm-datapower

I have tried to setup public key connection between AIX to AIX and that's working and I am facing problem while I setup same public key connection between AIX and DataPower appliance.

I could see in logs that's connection established but while using public I am not able to login and everytime expecting to enter password manually.

Can someone please help on this?

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: ./***_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
```

Answer (score 18):

There are many, many reasons why client-side debugging (`ssh -vvv ...`) shows:

```
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

Many of these are listed in the answers to [SSH public key won't send to server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131886/73128) on *Unix & Linux*, but, unfortunately, the client does not give any indication as to which one applies.

When I was struggling with this, my main problem was getting *server*-side logging/debugging to show. Of great help was the following (paraphrased) suggestion taken from [Ciro Santilli 冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功](https://serverfault.com/a/868391/233915)'s answer to [How to check sshd log?](https://serverfault.com/a/868391/233915) on *ServerFault*:

> Start a new SSH Server instance on a new port in debug mode with:
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
> ```
>
> then connect to it from the client with:
>
> ```
> ssh -p 2222 user@host
> ```

Comment: In my case I used `-vv`, but it helped in any-case

Comment: One possible cause is that the login shell for the account is set incorrectly in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222` helped show the connection was not working. `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -p 2222` gave that extra level of debug for me to see my key type was not allowed : )

Answer (score 14):

If you have sudo access to the destination server, check the SSH logs (/var/log/secure), it may give you some clue. For my case it was a bad permission on the home directory.

```
chmod g-w /home/user
chmod 700 /home/user/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Reference: https://chemicloud.com/kb/article/ssh-authentication-refused-bad-ownership-or-modes-for-directory/

Comment: Also check the ownership of `.ssh` directory: `ls -lhd .ssh`, it should be the same user. This is stupid but I encountered it and struggled for 30 minutes.

Comment: Actually it should be `chmod go-w /home/user`. I guess that was a typo on your part. I could edit your answer but I don't like to do that so you or someone else might like to do so.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same problem
(when I checked in my system there is `.ssh/authorized_keys` : the filename was wrong)
this way:

```
cp -p .ssh/authorised_keys .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I've a promlem: iso public key copy into `.ssh/authorized_keys` private key

Comment: I can't believe the problem was in this after all debugging and changing folder permissions :)

Answer (score 6):

Refer to this answer [SSH public key won't send to server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276903/247323).
In your log

> Offering RSA public key: ./***_rsa.pub
> ...
> we did not send a packet, disable method

It means that the client didn't send the key file. So make sure the key file exists.

1. Check the key file is in your local path
2. Make sure the public key content is copied into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in remote server.

Answer (score 5):

Check the ssh configuration on remote server to find if remote system is accepting type of key being passed.

Check the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and look for property `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` to confirm that it accepts key type being passed. For instance, here the key type seems to be `ssh-rsa`, so that should be added to the list of `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` 
(or for maximium compatibility `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes *`)

Once added, restart sshd daemon

EX:

```
sudo sed -i "/.*PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes.*/d"     /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -i "/.*RSAAuthentication.*/d"          /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -i "/.*PubkeyAuthentication.*/d"       /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -i "/.*PasswordAuthentication.*/d"     /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo sed -i "/.*PermitRootLogin.*/d"            /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes *"   | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "RSAAuthentication yes"      | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PubkeyAuthentication yes"   | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PasswordAuthentication no"  | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "PermitRootLogin no"         | sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl restart sshd.service
sudo systemctl status  sshd.service | grep -i success
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Messing with Open SUSE's Micro OS, noticed /etc/ssh/sshd_config didn't exist so I had to create it, and couldn't for the life of me get it to work. What worked for me was cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, saw my elliptic curve cryptography public key started with ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3...; sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config; (added "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ed25519"); sudo systemctl restart sshd; and success :), I also went back and found out adding PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes *, works as well, so that should probably be the answer)

Comment: It now makes perfect sense "debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method" means the client didn't send the key, because it wasn't an accepted key type, without PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes *, hum at this point I might as well edit the answer from 99% correct to 100% correct

Answer (score 2):

So what happened for me is that I have 2 VMs to access from my local machine (2 keys `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa2.pub`). I realized that my ssh connection is using id_rsa.pub by default for any `ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx` connection. I solved my issue by adding a config file and specify the identity to be used for every host like the following :

```
vi ~/.ssh/config

Add both hostnames and their identity file as follows:

Host server1.nixcraft.com
  IdentityFile ~/Users/.ssh/id_rsa1
Host server2.nixcraft.com
  IdentityFile ~/Users/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem. Two raspberry Pis on my local network - one connected, one didn't (with the 'debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method' error)

after 4 hours I found the problem 
Being used to uk spelling I created the 'authorised_users' file not 'authorized_users'

Doh !!

Comment: Did you mean `authorized_keys`?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and, after several hours banging my head against the wall, I realized there was a typo in the public key file. Instead of beginning with

```
ssh-rsa
```

there was a `+` sign at the beginning:

```
+ssh-rsa
```

I know it's obvious in retrospect, but it doesn't hurt to double check your file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there can be a lot of things causing this problem. In my case I forgot to specified the **User** name in my ~/.ssh/config file. Apparently, it depends on your current login name.

```
Host dev
HostName 1.2.3.4
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
User John
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config you have the following entry

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

as opposed to

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss #this is the correct entry
```

After updating this, be sure to issue a

> sudo systemctl restart sshd #Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Think about selinux, if is enabled,do:

```
# sudo ausearch -c "sshd" --raw | audit2allow -M my-sshd  
# sudo semodule -i my-sshd.pp
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and tried every instruction given here and after several hours of troubleshooting, I noticed the SSH server (which is my router) does not have a support for `ed25519`. Dropbear was spamming the following log: `Pubkey auth attempt with unknown algo...`

Using an `RSA` type fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who have the log "we did not send a packet, disable method" when trying to use a public key.
Check your sshd_config file on the remote server and force "PubkeyAuthentication" to "yes", even if it should be "yes" by default.
For me it solved my connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

my case solved with removing and creating new id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.
if you don't need your "private public" key. remove them and create new with:

> ssh-keygen

Answer (score -2):

In my case the private key must have been added to the agent with:

```sh
ssh-add ~/.ssh/private_id_rsa
```